# Why did Tokyo start a mutiny against Palermo?

Tags: plot-explanation, money-heist

In the first episode of season 4 of *Money Heist*, Tokyo decides to take command against the current leader Palermo, thus organizing a mutiny. The course of events that led to this does not make sense to me.

1. First Palermo says that they should operate Nairobi and he orders to give her total anesthesia
2. Nairobi refuses and asks to be surrendered to the police
3. At this point Tokyo and Helsinki take her side, disregarding Palermo's authority

It seems that the mutiny originates from this disagreement, and, in fact

4. Palermo steps down and leaves the command to Tokyo

But here's the bit that doesn't make sense to me:

5. Tokyo assumes command and orders to operate Nairobi, just like Palermo wanted. And everybody proceeds without questioning that decision.

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the same time, Palermo both made a compelling argument against releasing Nairobi, but also caused people to no longer want him in charge. Effectively, even though he had a point, the way in which he argued that point made him an untrustworthy leader from that point on.

Answer (score -2):

The main reason of Tokyo took command, because of her overconfidence and greed. Nairobi is the one to convince Tokyo to be the leader, as she is a feminist, so only wanted girls to be the lead. So, Tokyo intentionally took command from Palermo. She also told Professor that, she took command, because Palermo gone crazy. But Palermo gone crazy, only after she took command from him. So Tokyo's foolish actions lead to the death of Nairobi. She said Palermo lost all their trust, but just before this incident, she got drunk & roamed all over the Bank. There was never a leadership quality seen in her. She didn't even know the plan, but just wanted to be the leader & take command from the OG mastermind behind this plan. Nairobi did the same before. She took command from Berlin before. But, she didn't know, he is a mastermind & planned a heist, which is harder than professor's heist. And she can't handle the heat & returned it to Berlin. But, Nairobi still Insisting Tokyo, another woman to command, tells how rude of a feminist she is. But in this case, Tokyo knows that, Palermo is one of the masterminds behind the plan, but still manages to get command from him. This lead to Nairobi's death & the harsh times of the gang. So Tokyo taking command is just for her greed to be the leader.

Comment: The question was why, if getting Nairobi proper medical care was the ostensible reason for Tokyo taking over, Tokyo didn't actually change how Nairobi was cared for?